# Why are Serif endings still needed at all?

Tags: fonts, font-design, history, serif

Serif endings are a curious thing of the past that, to me, they don´t seem to have any real purpose today, except remind the forms of the past.
We have to admit that Serif fonts are more legible, but not necessarily because of the serif ending (right?) but because of the difference in thickness of different parts of the letter.
Can you give reasons why serif endings still make sense or are practical and useful?
Do you know any fonts that don´t have serif endings but have different thickness traits?

Comment: Well if you were to do analysis on text from a blurred image its clear that having the endings helps to get a better match. So i see no reason why the serifs wouldnt be useful. Sure lost sof modulated sans serif fonts around though.

Comment: Serifs serve the same purpose today as they did in the 1700s. Human are still humans.

Comment: Absolutely. `* blinks with a third lizard eyelid *`

Comment: Relevant reading :-) https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45725/why-use-sans-serif-at-all?rq=1

Comment: Not everything has to be "useful". Serif fonts exist mainly because of tradition. It started with the ancient Greeks.  You might as well ask why the Ancient Greeks added serifs to carved letters. The answer is not simple however, as there are various theories.